# How to customize filters in activity timeline?

Tags: lightning-experience, activityhistory

I want to add custom filters to display last 2 years activities in activity timeline. Currently only few filters are there.

Is there any way to customize this feature.

[image: Salesforce Activity Timeline]

Answer (score 0):

Currently its not possible to create custom filters on activity time lines.

Refer the [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdeCEUAZ/ability-to-customize-activity-timeline-filters)